# Setting cookies without navbar dissapearing

Tags: php, html, cookies, header, navbar

What I am trying to do is setup a upvote/downvote system on my website using cookies (to try and allow anonymous users to participate). The issue I am running into is I have to set my cookies before my headers, and for some reason, whenever I click the upvote or downvote button, my navbar dissapears and then reappears. The index file is here:

```
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';
include 'postbuttons.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Announcments</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.php">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<?php include '../header.html'; ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include 'pagination.php';
include 'content.php';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

my dbconnect file is:

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'databasename';
$db_user = 'databaseuser';
$db_pass = 'databasepassword';
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
$res = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=" . $_SESSION['user']);

if ($res != false) {
    $userRow = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
}
?>
```

my post buttons page, which is where i think the problem is:

```
<?php 
$posts = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM blog");
//$posts = mysqli_fetch_array($postsraw, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($posts as $ind) {
setcookie('test'.$ind['id'], 'heck you');
$id = $ind['id'];
$postraw = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id=$id");
$post = mysqli_fetch_array($postraw, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if (isset($_POST['vote'.$id])) {
    $postcookie = 'vote' . $id;
    if (isset($_COOKIE[$postcookie])) {
        $data = json_decode($_COOKIE[$postcookie]);
    } else {
        $data = ['neither', '#aaa'];
    }
    if ($_POST['votetype'.$id] == 'up') {
        if (!isset($_COOKIE[$postcookie]) || $data[0] == 'neither' || 
$data[0] == 'down') {
        if ($data[0] == 'down') {
            $change = $post['upvote'] + 1;
            $sql = "UPDATE blog SET upvote=$change WHERE id=$id";
            $query = $conn->query($sql);
            $changedown = $post['downvote'] - 1;
            $othersql = "UPDATE blog SET downvote=$changedown WHERE id=$id";
            $newquery = $conn->query($othersql);
        } else {
            $change = $post['upvote'] + 1;
            $sql = "UPDATE blog SET upvote=$change WHERE id=$id";
            $query = $conn->query($sql);
        }
        $cookievalue = ['up', 'green'];
        setcookie($postcookie, json_encode($cookievalue));
        } else {
            $change = $post['upvote'] - 1;
            $sql = "UPDATE blog SET upvote=$change WHERE id=$id";
            $query = $conn->query($sql);
            $cookievalue = ['neither', '#aaa'];
            setcookie($postcookie, json_encode($cookievalue));
        }
    }
    if ($_POST['votetype'.$id] == 'down') {
        if (!isset($_COOKIE[$postcookie]) || $data[0] == 'neither' || 
$data[0] == 'up') {
            if ($data[0] == 'up') {
                $change = $post['downvote'] + 1;
                $sql = "UPDATE blog SET downvote=$change WHERE id=$id";
                $query = $conn->query($sql);
                $changedown = $post['upvote'] - 1;
                $othersql = "UPDATE blog SET upvote=$changedown WHERE 
id=$id";
                $newquery = $conn->query($othersql);
            } else {
                $change = $post['downvote'] + 1;
                $sql = "UPDATE blog SET downvote=$change WHERE id=$id";
                $query = $conn->query($sql);
            }
            $cookievalue = ['down', 'red'];
            setcookie($postcookie, json_encode($cookievalue));
            } else {
                $change = $post['downvote'] - 1;
                $sql = "UPDATE blog SET downvote=$change WHERE id=$id";
                $query = $conn->query($sql);
                $cookievalue = ['neither', '#aaa'];
                setcookie($postcookie, json_encode($cookievalue));
            }
    }
    echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=#'.$id.'">';
}
if(isset($_POST['report'.$id])) {

    if(isset($_COOKIE['report'.$id])) {
        $cdata = json_decode($_COOKIE['report'.$id]);
    } else {
        $cdata = ['notset', 'black'];
    }
    if ($cdata[0] == 'notset') {
        $reportval = ['reported', 'red'];
        setcookie('report'.$id, json_encode($reportval));
        $change = $post['reports'] + 1;
        $sql = $conn->query("UPDATE blog SET reports=$change WHERE id=$id");
    } else {
        $reportval = ['notset', 'black'];
        setcookie('report'.$id, json_encode($reportval));
        $change = $post['reports'] - 1;
        $sql = $conn->query("UPDATE blog SET reports=$change WHERE id=$id");
    }
    echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=#'.$id.'">';
}
}
?>
```

and if it helps, this is my content.php page:

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" data- 
toggle="modal" 
data-target="#announcmentm">
Add
</button><h1>Announcments:</h1>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="announcmentm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Add Announcment</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <?php include 'create.php' ?>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM blog");
$pager = new Paginater();
$pager->paginate('blog', 5, $id);
?>
```

and finally my header.html page:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">STUCO</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/suggestions.html">Suggestions</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/tasks">Tasks</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/blog">Blog</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

you can see the problem I am describing here: https://stuco.baccaw.host/blog
just try and upvote one of the articles and you will see the navbar dissapear for a bit, then come back.

Comment: Just tested - the navbar isn't actually disappearing, it's just that the page is reloading and redirecting you to a URL with a hash portion that means you're not right at the top of the page. How to fix depends on what exactly you're wanting...

Comment: Although I imagine the best solution would be to make the "like" functionality do it's thing via Ajax and therefore not reload the page at all

Comment: I had thought about that, but I am not very versed in ajax so I thought I would try and get around it.